# MySQL fulltext search gives higher rank size for more word occurences in row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing, full-text-search

"fulltext indexing is such that the more 'words' (of greater than the minimum length) that appear in the columns you index, the greater will be the value of the returned row rank"

---

If I search for 'apple':

Now -

> 'apple for me, apple for you, apple for stackoverflow'

has higher search rank than

> 'I eat apple'

because in the first row 'apple' occurs 3 times more that the other one.

**How can I tune the fulltext search to give the same search rank to the two rows ?**

---

Sample Query:

```
SELECT 
title, description, MATCH (title, description) 
AGAINST ('apple' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM my_table
WHERE MATCH(title, description) AGAINST('apple')
```

Sample Table:

```
+----+--------+------------------------------------------------------+
| id | title  | description                                          |
+----+--------+------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | one    | apple for me, apple for you, apple for stackoverflow |
|  2 | two    | I eat apple                                          |
+----+--------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Will you please add query to the question?

Comment: MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?  (Try both)  What happens without `IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is unfortunately that you cannot configure mysql's fulltext plugin not to consider the number of times the searched word appears in the data in the weighting calculation. See [this documentation on what you can configure in fulltext searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).

Use like or rlike to achive this result, otherwise you need to change the source code of the fulltext plugin.

Comment: I home someone suggest some hack for this behavior because I need full text search but in my website I do not want the number of word occurrence to impact the row search rank.

Comment: You may have to turn to alternative solutions, such as sphinx to achive the desired results then.